# ORA-12541 No listener

Tags: database, oracle, connection

I read other question but I I couldn’t solve it.
This is my connection code to Oracle.

```
username = "labdb"
password = "labdb"
databaseName = "localhost/test"
connection = cx_Oracle.connect(username, password, databaseName)
```

And I receive the same error: `cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-12541: TNS:no listener`

Comment: Are the database and listener started? What is the output of `lsnrctl status`?

Comment: How can I check if database and listener started? And what is it lsnrct?

Comment: Have you installed Oracle database (not just client) on your host?

Comment: lsnrctl is the command line control utility for the listener.

Comment: Can you link me a complete guide?

Comment: Start here, with the XE edition: https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/xe.html

Comment: I'm working on Mac OS

Comment: The only _supported_ option, assuming you have an Intel CPU, is to use Oracle VirtualBox to run an Oracle Linux VM and run the database on that. If you have a newer M.1 processor then you're out of luck; Oracle won't run on it at all.